# \S Regular Expression

Tags: regex, awk

Can someone give me an example of \S in a regular expression working? My understanding is that it should match any line that does not begin with \t, \n, etc.

If this is my file:

```
test
\ttesting

cat testfile | awk '/\S/ {print}'
```

Produces no output but I'd expect it to output the \ttesting. I haven't found a good example of what \S is supposed to do or how to get it to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do not think the `\S` flag is supported in all implementations of `awk`. It is not listed under Regular Expression Operators in the [documentation](http://www.math.utah.edu/docs/info/gawk_5.html#SEC28). Your version of `awk` may or may not support it.

Another easy command line tool which *does* support it is `grep`. However, for your purposes, you need to specify that you only want to match non-whitespace at the **beginning of string**, so you need to use the `^` operator to do beginning of string.

```
cat testfile | grep  '^\S'
```

Output:

```
testing
```

Comment: @BMW, Can you find any documentation supporting this and provide a version number?

Comment: @BMW, I just amended my ansewr, since your version must obviously support it.

Comment: It appears to not be supported by my version of awk.

Answer (score 1):

As written, `/\S/` matches if there is a non-whitespace character anywhere in the line.  Thus it matches both lines.  It sounds like you want to match on the beginning of the line:

```
$ cat testfile | awk '/^\S/ {print}'
test
$ cat testfile | awk '/^\s/ {print}'
        testing
```

The caret `^` matches only at the beginning of a line.  From the first example above, `/^\S/`matches on any line whose first character after the beginning of the line is a non-whitespace character.  Thus, it matches the first line in your test file.

The second example does the opposite: it matches if the first character after the start of the line is a whitespace character (`\s` is the opposite of `\S`: it matches whitespace).  Thus, it matches the line that starts with a tab.

The behavior of `\S` and `\s` are documented in [section 3.5 of the GNU awk manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html#GNU-Regexp-Operators) which states:

> \s
>       Matches any whitespace character. Think of it as shorthand for [[:space:]].
>
> \S
>       Matches any character that is not whitespace. Think of it as shorthand for [^[:space:]].

Answer (score 0):

```
\S
```

> When the UNICODE flags is not specified, matches any non-whitespace
>   character; this is equivalent to the set [^ \t\n\r\f\v] The LOCALE
>   flag has no extra effect on non-whitespace match. If UNICODE is set,
>   then any character not marked as space in the Unicode character
>   properties database is matched.

https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html

Answer (score 0):

Here is the sample:

```
cat -A file

sdf$
        $
test$
^Itesting$
$
$
^I^I^I^I$
asdf$
afd afd$
```

so after run in gnu awk v4.1

```
awk '/\S/' file

sdf
test
        testing
asdf
afd afd
```

It removes all empty lines or while space line (line with only space, tab, or enter, etc)

here is my awk version in cygwin

```
awk --version |head -1
GNU Awk 4.1.0, API: 1.0 (GNU MPFR 3.1.2, GNU MP 4.3.2)
```

refer link: [The GNU Awk User's Guide](http://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html)

```
3.5 gawk-Specific Regexp Operators

GNU software that deals with regular expressions provides a number of additional regexp operators. These operators are described in this section and are specific to gawk; they are not available in other awk implementations. Most of the additional operators deal with word matching. For our purposes, a word is a sequence of one or more letters, digits, or underscores (‘_’):

\s
Matches any whitespace character. Think of it as shorthand for [[:space:]].


\S
Matches any character that is not whitespace. Think of it as shorthand for [^[:space:]].


\w
Matches any word-constituent character—that is, it matches any letter, digit, or underscore. Think of it as shorthand for [[:alnum:]_].


\W
Matches any character that is not word-constituent. Think of it as shorthand for [^[:alnum:]_].
```

Answer (score 0):

```
\S is everything excluded by \s
```

`\s means [\r\n\t\f ]` so better watch out. If you dont want to print out the strings beginning with \t then only use `\S`

for strings beginning with any of `\r\t\n\f` you need `\s`

so NOT `\s` is `\S`

so you can guess it: `\s + \S means everything` i.e. equivalent to `.*`